# Snowmix streaming from Gstreamer via RTMP shows black screen on RTMP server

Tags: udp, streaming, gstreamer, rtmp, wowza

I am using Snowmix to mix media sources and Gstreamer to stream via RTMP the Snowmix output to a Wowza RTMP server.

Using the following Gstreamer pipeline whilst using the `text_tutorial.ini` Snowmix test input can be viewed via VLC:

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/mixer1 do-timestamp=true is-live=true !\ 
'video/x-raw, format=BGRA, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, interlace-mode=progressive, framerate=24/1, width=1024, height=576' !\ 
videoconvert !\
x264enc !\
mpegtsmux !\
udpsink host=192.168.78.10 port=4012 sync=true
```

Opening VLC media player and pointing it at the specified ip address plays the stream successfully.

However when attempting to stream to RTMP the output from the Wowza server that receives the stream detects that there is a stream and reports that it is playing back the stream but displays a black screen using this pipeline:

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/mixer1 do-timestamp=true is-live=true !\
'video/x-raw, format=BGRA, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, interlace-mode=progressive, framerate=24/1, width=1024, height=576' !\
videoconvert !\
x264enc !\
flvmux streamable=true !\
rtmpsink location='rtmp://192.168.78.10:1935/live/RTMPStream'
```

As shown above the only difference between the two pipelines are the final two lines which prepare the stream for their respective endpoints. But when attempting to play the RTMP stream on Wowza we receive a black screen.

What could be missing from the pipeline?

Comment: Hi Sir! Did you solve the problem? I also have the same error. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not. Let me know if you find out anything yourself.

Comment: Are you sure Wowza accept streams with no sound? And also are there any requirements for the stream sent to Wowza?